# generating id containing current date and counter

Tags: java

i am trying to exeute the code for generating an id for records in sql that contains todays date and a counter concatinated. the problem is when i try to hit the generate button the id generates the current date but i want the counter to reinitialize to 1 on the next day or on the date change which in not initializing ny help please .

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyCalendarUtil {

    private static String buffer = "";
    private static int counter = 1;

    public String nextID() {
        final String datePrefix = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());

        if (Long.parseLong(returnMaxId()) > 0) {
            MyCalendarUtil.counter = Integer.parseInt(returnMaxId().substring(8, returnMaxId().length()));
        }

        if (buffer.equals(datePrefix)) {
            MyCalendarUtil.counter++;
        } else {
            MyCalendarUtil.buffer = datePrefix;
            MyCalendarUtil.counter = 1;
        }

        String suffix = "";

        if (MyCalendarUtil.counter <= 1000) {

            if (validateRange(0, 9, MyCalendarUtil.counter)) {
                suffix += "00" + counter;
            } else if (validateRange(10, 99, MyCalendarUtil.counter)) {
                suffix += "0" + counter;
            } else if (validateRange(99, 999, MyCalendarUtil.counter)) {
                suffix += counter;
            }
        }

        return (datePrefix + suffix);
    }

    public boolean validateRange(int min, int max, int field) {
        return field >= min && field <= max;
    }

    public String returnMaxId() {
        String result = "";
        try {
            DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
            Connection connection = util.getConnection();
            ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT MAX(id) AS 'lastId' FROM crap ");
            if (rs.next()) {
                result = (rs.getString(1) != null) ? rs.getString(1) : "0";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you need to listen to the day change property of calender. Below code might help you....

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class DateChangeEx {

    private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    private static int counter = 1;
    public static void main(String[] a){

        Calendar cal = MyCal.getInstance();

        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("before updating counter--->");
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.println(""+(counter++)+cal.getTime());
        }

        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        System.out.println("After updating counter--->");
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.println(""+(counter++)+cal.getTime());
        }
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }

    private class ChangeListner implements PropertyChangeListener{

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            counter = 0;

        }

    }

    private class MyCal extends GregorianCalendar{

        public void add(int field, int amount){
            Date oldVal = this.getTime(); 
            super.add(field, amount);

            changeSupport.firePropertyChange("calender", oldVal, this.getTime());
        }
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListner(PropertyChangeListener listner){
        changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listner);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListner(PropertyChangeListener listner){
        changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listner);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am trying to run this program in netbeans and when the date is changed the counter should reinitialize and if i restart my windows application the counter should resume to its position or the previous id which i have successfully submitted to the database

Comment: so the program above is not the complete solution. It doesn't cover the part of accessing the db and getting the 'previous position'. Rather the program above should give you complete conceptual understanding how your solution should be.